# Non-integral Constant declaration - dev-c++ - error: `type' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, constants, declaration, dev-c++

I have a Non-integral Constant declaration in a class.

I keep getting the following:

> ComponentClass.h:14: error: template declaration of `const typename ComponentClass<T>  ::position NULLPOSITION` 
>   ComponentClass.h:14: error: position was not declared in this scope
>   ComponentClass.h:14: error: expected `;` before numeric constant

Please find below my code.

ComponentClass.h

```
#ifndef _ComponentClass_H
#define _ComponentClass_H

template< class T>
class ComponentClass
{
public:

       typedef ComponentClass* position;
       ComponentClass();
};

template<class T>
const typename ComponentClass<T>::position NULLPOSITION=(position)0;

template<class T>
ComponentClass<T>::ComponentClass(){}
#endif
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Declare a non integral constant class member for a templated class. Anayway I tryed resolved by following jon purdy's answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you’re seeing this error is that `position` is not in scope in the expression `(position)0`. You can omit the cast altogether (i.e, `0`). If you wanted to include it, you would need to use `typename ComponentClass<T>::position` as you did in the definition of `NULLPOSITION`.

You appear to be defining a static member variable without first declaring it in the class like so:

```
static const position NULLPOSITION;
```

Then you can define it outside the class as you do now. In order to avoid redundant definitions, however, the typical solution is as follows:

```
// ComponentBase.h
class ComponentBase {
public:
    typedef ComponentBase* position;
    static const position NULLPOSITION;
};

// ComponentClass.h
template<class T>
class ComponentClass : public ComponentBase { ... };

// ComponentBase.cpp
const ComponentBase::position ComponentBase::NULLPOSITION = 0;
```

That is, don’t make `NULLPOSITION` a member of every instantiation of `ComponentClass`, but instead let all `ComponentClass` instantiations share a single definition.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because he is trying to declare and define a member `NULLPOSITION` simultaneously outside of the class. The `typedef` is a red herring.

Comment: @JonPurdy: What makes you think that's a member? Maybe it _should_ be, but it isn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: there are no non-member template variables in C++.

Comment: @n.m.: Correct, and _that's_ the OP's problem (see the first sentence of my answer).

Comment: @JonPurdy: Your edit is better, but now you've significantly altered the semantics of the `position` type, and it's not clear to me that that type has any intrinsic value at all when you do it this way.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I find your comment surprising. Could you explain your reasoning about `position`? I don’t think it’s *necessary*, but I left it intact in accordance with the question.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I'll answer your question with a question: what's the value of `position`, now that it's a pointer type that simply never changes. And, by extension, what's the use now of `NULLPOSITION`? It seems to me that there is no value in this "wrapping" of the semantics of a `ComponentBase*`, whereas for any `Component<T>*` the same is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Thanks. Your answer put me on the right track. Coupled with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744823/c-non-integral-template-const-initialization-expected-init-declarator-before-c I was abe to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to define a sort of "template variable", but no such feature exists in C++.

You also failed to qualify the second place at which you write `position` in that same line of code.

These two factors are the cause of your errors.

---

It *may* make *some* sense for `NULLPOSITION` to be a static member of instances of the class template:

```
template< class T>
class ComponentClass
{
public:

       typedef ComponentClass* position;
       static const position NULLPOSITION;

       ComponentClass();
};
```

But now, as far as I can tell, you have to define it for each `T` you want to use, which rather sucks:

```
template<>
const ComponentClass<int>::position ComponentClass<int>::NULLPOSITION =
    static_cast<ComponentClass<int>::position>(0);

template<>
const ComponentClass<double>::position ComponentClass<double>::NULLPOSITION =
    static_cast<ComponentClass<double>::position>(0);
```

Instead perhaps make `position` be a bit more clever than a mere pointer type — let it be a proper user-defined type with a default constructor that initialises the object to a "null" state. Function objects work in this way, for example; `std::function<void()>()` is a valid, but *singular* function object.

Comment: Though it could've been a cool feature :)